# Tomcat caching on startup

Tags: tomcat

This is a general question about the behavior of Tomcat.

I understand that Tomcat caches files to the `temp` directory, but I am unclear about how this caching behaves.  The reason I ask is that I am writing some Chef ServerSpec integration tests and need to ensure that some files are created upon startup without the need to manually create them.

My question is **does Tomcat cache files upon starting the server?  If not, what is required for it to cache a file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching takes many forms.

For static files (HTML, CSS, etc) Tomcat does not cache any files on startup. By default there is a static file cache with a relatively short TTL of 5 seconds. Files are placed in the cache on first access.

Class files (including Servlets) are loaded into memory on first access.

JSPs are (by default) transformed to Servlets, compiled and loaded into memory on first access. How often they are checked for changes depends on configuration.

In some configurations, Tomcat will extract files from archives on web application start and use the extracted version for performance reasons.

Internally, web applications may cache but Tomcat has neither visibility nor control over that.